# Unit testing with NSURLConnection

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, networking, mocking

I want to test a piece of code that uses network (the `NSURLConnection` class, to be specific). The code (let’s call it `NetworkManager`) looks a bit like this:

```
- (id) buildConnection
{
    // some more code and then:
    return [NSURLConnection …];
}

- (void) startNetworkSync
{
    id connection = [self buildConnection];
    //…
}
```

In the unit test I would like to get rid of the networking, ie. replace the `NSURLConnection` object by a mock. How do I do this?

I’ve tried creating a partial mock of the `NetworkManager` that would replace the `buildConnection` method by a stub. The problem is that partial mocks as done by [OCMock](http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/software/OCMock/) only stub messages from the outside world – sending `buildConnection` from the `startNetworkSync` invokes the original method, not the stub.

I have also tried monkey-patching the `NetworkManager` class through a category. This works, I can easily override the `buildConnection` method by other code and replace the real `NSURLConnection` with a stub. The problem is that I found no simple way I could get the stubbed connection in the test – the connection is a private part of the `NetworkManager`.

Then I could subclass the `NetworkManager`, override the `buildConnection` method and add an instance variable plus an accessor for the created connection. This seems like a lot of code, though.

How would you solve this? I am looking for a solution that keeps the `NetworkManager` class design clean and does not require much magic nor much code in the test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the kind of thing dependency injection is designed to solve; if you use `startNetworkSyncWithConnection:(NSURLConnection*)` instead you can easily test the method with a mock connection. If you don't want to change the API for your clients you could even keep `startNetworkSync` as a wrapper that does nothing but call that new method with `[self buildConnection]` as the argument.

Comment: OK, I’ve more or less done it this way. The clients know nothing about network, they only send and receive data, but I’ve added the method to inject a ‘foreign’ connection to the process, which helps in testing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I modified OCMock to support real partial mocks, see the [repo on GitHub](http://github.com/mmangino/OCMock).

Comment: Thanks. I’ve already solved the problem, but real partial mocks would be handy. Any chance of merging the code with the vanilla OCMock?

Comment: Yes, the author of OCMock is in the process of merging. He's going to try to make it even cleaner during the merge.

Comment: has this been merged in yet? If so, please provide an example on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I have used recently is to completely abstract the networking interface. If the class needs some data from the network, it probably interacts with some server service that can be explictly modelled as a protocol:

```
@protocol SomeNetworkService
- (NSArray*) allAvailableFoos;
- (void) insertNewFoo: (Foo*) foo;
@end
```

And then you’ll have a real HTTP implementation and a testing one. This means more work, but also much better testability. The tests are less brittle and much more convenient, since the testing network layer can do whatever you need.